# java multi-dimensional array fails with a nullpointerexception

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

I get nullpointerexception when I try to fill a 2D array with process IDs, it is 2D since there is a unlimited list of PIDs for each system and I need to eventually return that back to my main code (set to void now since just a prototype test function).

Any ideas would be great

```
private void testfunctionA (List<String> additionalPC) {

    // A 2d array that will contain a list of pids for each system - needs to be strings and not integers
    String[][] pidCollection = new String[additionalPC.size()][];

    // Go through one system at a time
    for (int i=0; i < additionalPC.size(); i++) {

            // Get pids for apple per system
            String listofpids = Driver.exec("ssh " +  additionalPayloads.get(i) + " ps -ef | grep -i apple | grep -v \"grep -i apple\" | awk \\' {print $2}\\'");

            // Works ok for printing for one system
            System.out.println(listofpids);
            // put the list of pids into a string array - they are separated by rows
            String[] tempPid = listofpids.split("\n");

            // Put the string array into the 2d array - put this fails with a NPE
            for (int j=0; j < tempPid.length; j++) {
                    pidCollection[i][j] = tempPid[j];
            }

            System.out.println(pidCollection);


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created your 2D array, but the array is full of `null` 1D arrays.  Each element in the 2D array needs to have a 1D array created.  You've already created it with `tempPid`; just use it.  Instead of

```
for (int j=0; j < tempPid.length; j++) {
    pidCollection[i][j] = tempPid[j];
}
```

just use

```
pidCollection[i] = tempPid;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!
also realized that i shouldn't be printing a multi-dimensional array like I did in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize each element of pidCollection:

```
String[] tempPid = listofpids.split("\n");

pidCollection[i] = new String[tempPid.length];

// Put the string array into the 2d array - put this fails with a NPE
for (int j=0; j < tempPid.length; j++) {
        pidCollection[i][j] = tempPid[j];
}
```

or, in this case, more simply:

```
pidCollection[i] = listofpids.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you need to define the second dimention of your array

```
String[][] pidCollection = new String[additionalPC.size()][?????]; //this initialises the` first axis
```

Long answer:
You're not abliged to do it on that line, and you can do it on a case by case basis for each first dimention, eg

```
pidCollection[i]=new String[tempPid.length] //this initialised the second axis for a particular i
```

but you need to do it at some point, easiest solution is to define both dimentions at once unless you have a reason not to. Although I think that may not be applicable in this case so use the case by case method

Comment: There's no way for me to know the size of the PID list beforehand so I cannot give a fixed length beforehand. And the previous solution worked. Thanks for the input though